# Concatenate a string filter in where

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to concatenate my filter string in my Linq-to-SQL request. It's a first time I'm new in c# and Linq.

```
string f = "where 1==1";
            if (!string.Equals(t, "0"))
            {
                f += " AND p.lId==" + a;           
            }
            if (!string.Equals(tc, "0"))
            {
                f += " AND p.tp.Id==" + b;
            }
```

I want to replace this string with my `where` in the Linq query like this

```
var req = from p in db.Pt
                         +f+
                         select new { L= p.bt, Lg = p.Sl };
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. It will open you up to SQL injection.

Comment: With regards to the comment from @Arran , you should definitely look into perameterized queries, which is one of the main implementations to stop SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do can be achieved with LINQ `Where` methods:

```
var req = db.Pt;

if (!string.Equals(t, "0"))
{
    req = req.Where(p => p.lId == a);
}

if (!string.Equals(tc, "0"))
{
    req = req.Where(p => p.tp.Id == b);
}

req = req.Select(p = >  new { L= p.bt, Lg = p.Sl });
```

Comment: Just about to answer the same. This is the way to go

Comment: I try it but it tells me System.Linq.IQueryable<Myapp.Model.Pt> to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyApp.Model.Pt>

Comment: That's because you are casting it to DbSet. Why you need that? Once you query the DbSet, you have a IQueryable, not a DbSet.

Answer (score 0):

I discourage the use string concatenation for linq but if you actually need it (and I mean weird scenarios), you could try DynamicLinq

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I try it but it tells me System.Linq.IQueryable<Myapp.Model.Pt> to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyApp.Model.Pt>

Comment: I don't understand, what have you try? I'm asking because I saw the same comment in different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var query = from p in db.Pt
            select p;

if (!string.Equals(t, "0"))
{
  query = query.Where(p => p.lId== a);
}

if (!string.Equals(tc, "0"))
{
   query = query.Where(p => p.tp.Id== ba);
}

var req = from p in query
          select new { L= p.bt, Lg = p.Sl };
```

Linq can be composed dynamically this way. If you now do a `req.ToList();` your query will be executed. Because of this lazy behavior you can compose your query in distinct steps.